# Let two renderui numeric inputs react on eachother in shiny

Tags: filter, shiny

I'm trying to create two `renderUI` filters that have a value dependent on each other. I have two filters: percentage and value. 
Percentage should be: `value/total_amount` and value should be `total_amount*percentage`. I need this because sometimes the user wants to fill in a number it wants and sometimes it wants a percentage of the total. And I always want to show both.
For example, if the user fills in .20 in the percentage filter, I want to show 20 in the value filter. And if the user fills in 80 in the value filter, I want to show .8 in the percentage filter.
 So I'm hoping these two can be combined.. I'm trying this code but it's obviously not working.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  total_amount<-100


  output$percentage<-renderUI({

   myvalue<- input$value/total_amount
   if(is.null(myvalue))myvalue<-.2
    # myvalue<-.2
   #browser()
    numericInput('percentage','percentage',value = myvalue)
  })

  output$value<-renderUI({

    myvalue<- input$percentage*total_amount
    if(is.null(myvalue))myvalue<-100
    # myvalue<-100
    numericInput('value','value',value = myvalue)
   })

}

  ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput('percentage'),
      uiOutput('value')

    )
    # ,mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot"))
  )
)

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the default value for the percentage and make sure that widget has a value.

```R
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {

  total_amount <- 100
  percentage <- 0.2

  output$percentage <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(input$value)) {
      myvalue <- percentage
    } else {
      myvalue <- input$value/total_amount
    }  
    numericInput('percentage', 'percentage', value = myvalue)
  })

  output$value <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(input$percentage)) {
      myvalue <- percentage*total_amount
    } else {
      myvalue <- input$percentage*total_amount
    }
    numericInput('value', 'value', value = myvalue)
   })

}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput('percentage'),
      uiOutput('value')

    )
    ,mainPanel()
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It does work, thanks. But for some reason it keeps on updating in my real app. I think it's because of rounding...